# how hide tap bar on another controller before show everything else

Tags: swift, swift2

I have a simple tap bar example. And for my next view i have a ViewController with tableView and on bottom textInput. when i want hide tap bar i have a code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject? {
    if segue.identifier == "showMe" {
        (segue.destinationViewController as! MyViewController)
            destinationController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
    }
}
```

and on my next view when i tap a row on tableView i see first rendering tap bar and then tap bar is hidden and on last input Edit goes down :( how hide this tap bar before show next screen ?

[image]

Comment: Can u please add code/screenshot showing the hierarchy of `UITabBarController` and `UINavigationController`

Comment: I think is wrong with Constrains, i will let You know....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't exactly the best solution, but its a workaround:

1. set `destinationController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = false`
2. set contraints properly in your view controller (as if there is no tab bar)
3. use the following code (as shown) in the view controller where you want to hide the tab bar:

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

       self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame = CGRectZero
       self.tabBarController?.tabBar.userInteractionEnabled = false
   }
   ```

This will make sure that the tab bar is hidden. Now the Autolayout constraints will make sure your view displays correctly with the tab bar height as zero.

Comment: You were right is wrong settings with constrains when tab bar appear constrains was change.